Adding a single .deb package for any distribution in a Debian repository (with reprepro)?
I manage a custom Debian repository for my Raspberry Pis, and this repository currently contains packages for stretch and bookworm distributions.
Now, say I have a single text file, say myapp.txt.config, which I want installed at /usr/local/etc/myapp.txt.config. I managed to package this file in a myapp-txt-config.deb file as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/781647/package-a-single-text-file-into-a-deb-possibly-on-msys2-mingw64
Is it possible to have only one .deb package file included in my custom Debian repository, and yet have this .deb package installable by both stretch and bookworm distribution (or indeed, any distribution - this is just a text file, after all) - and if so, could I do this setup with reprepro?
Currently, I understand that to have this debian package accessible by both stretch and bookworm distribution, I'd have to run:
reprepro -b debsdir/ includedeb stretch myapp-txt-config.deb
reprepro -b debsdir/ includedeb bookworm myapp-txt-config.deb

... however:

I think this will include two copies of the .deb file, one for each distribution
If I access this repository from ant distribution (which is not stretch or bookworm), I think this .deb package will not be accessible (to apt-get, apt, etc)

If not doable with reprepro, is there some sort of a manual setup that would help me achieve this (single .deb file in repository accessible by any distribution)?

stretch and bookworm are just names. Put "personal", "single", "stable", "all", or anything. It doesn't matter. Just the instruction on how to add the line in sources.list (and in better: just one, without need to tell user to edit the distribution name.
